# Disable right click on pdf inside embed element

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have an `embed` element in which I provided path to `pdf` file. I want to prevent it from being download.

```
<embed src="test.pdf" width="760" height="800" oncontextmenu="return false" />
```

but when I right click on that t gives me options to save and print pdf. I want to prevent these options.

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>
```

but it disables right click on entire page except for PDF.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @grooveplex I want to prevent right click on pdf

Comment: You are aware of the fact that you can never stop users from downloading the pdf, even if you manage to prevent the context menu?

Comment: @Wendelin just want to make it bit difficult

Answer (score 5):

One simple and reliable solution, that is not affected by CORS or CSP, is to cover the embed with another element. I'm using an image here because you cannot embed pdfs on stack overflow.

```css
.embed-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  /* Just for demonstration, remove this part */
  opacity: 0.25;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Not Important*/
img {
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<h3>Normal img/embed/object element</h3>
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">

<hb/>

<h3>With cover</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
  <div class="embed-cover"></div>
</div>
```

The covering element 'catches' any click events and prevents them from reaching the underlying element (the image in this case)

Comment: Loved the idea but i can right click on your solution... I think you need to combine it with js in order to succeed blocking the click.

Comment: You can still right click but only on the div, not the embed/img, so there is no option to download or print.

Answer (score 1):

You should use iframe and inject your javascript code.

**To do:**

1. Use iframe tag instead of embed tag and use myFrame as id. ex:

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" width="760" height="800" />
```

2. In your parent document get iframe from DOM.
3. Call window.eval method of iframe, use

> ```
> 'document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
>         e.preventDefault();
>     }, false);'
> ```

as string parameter.

4. Now iframe should not effected by right click.

**It should look like this at the end:**

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');

myFrame.window.eval('document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false)');
```

Comment: Nope. The right click is still visible. (I created an object / iframe within a div, and adusted the top menu so the menu bar of PDF reader is above the other div that has "overflow:hidden". (so sabe / download buttons not visible) But seems whilst you can stop the context menu on the divs on page, you CANNOT disable an iframe or object context menu !)

Answer (score 0):

with Wendelin's answer i was able to achieve what i wanted to achieve.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .embed-cover {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
          
          /* Just for demonstration, remove this part */
          opacity: 0.25;
        }

        .wrapper {
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function disableContextMenu() {
            window.frames["pdfframe"].contentDocument.oncontextmenu = function(){return true;};   
            var myFrame = document.getElementById('pdfframe');
            myFrame.window.eval('document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false)');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="disableContextMenu();" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <embed id="pdfframe" src="<url of myfile.pdf>#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" ></embed>
        <div class="embed-cover"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Quick note, the styles for `.embed-cover` can be adjusted to set the bounds where right clicks are disabled

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use CSS to disable clics, but it will disable the scroll bar :

```
iframe {  
  pointer-events: none;  
}
```